# How can I use keycloak to protect my vue js pages and spring boot rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security, jhipster, keycloak

Recently I use jhipster to create a spring boot project which select keycloak to protect my rest api, and the application.properties like this:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: web_app
```

also, I create a vue project which select keycloak js to protect pages, the config like this:

```
import VueKeyCloak from '@dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js'

Vue.use(VueKeyCloak, {
  config: {
    realm: 'jhipster',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth',
    clientId: 'web_app'
  },
  onReady: (keycloak) => {
    console.log(keycloak.token)
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    })
  }
})
```

And we can see the vue project and spring project use the same keycloak client id, the Access Type is public in keycloak.
In vue project, I need to use username and password to log in, 
[image: log in page]
after log in I can get a token through keycloak.token, and I also set

```
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${Vue.prototype.$keycloak.token}`
```

when I call spring boot rest api. But not working, always return 401.
After several days hard working, I can not find the reason. Someone can help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you create a vue project on you own or use the jhipster vue js blueprint?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I changed url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9080/auth' to url: 'http://loaclhost:9080/auth' and the problem was disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the "Client authentication" of the client "web-app" you created, due to the vue app can only access public through username password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).